# How to do a pivot and conditional group in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have data like this:

```
[
  {
    "invoice_id": "GRS",
    "segment": "D",
    "metric": "2019",
    "revenue": 100,
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "RET",
    "segment": "D",
    "metric": "2019",
    "revenue": 100,
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "GRS",
    "segment": "R",
    "metric": "2020",
    "revenue": 100,
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "RET",
    "segment": "R",
    "metric": "2021",
    "revenue": 100,
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "GRS",
    "segment": "R",
    "metric": "2021",
    "revenue": 100,
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "RET",
    "segment": "D",
    "metric": "2020",
    "revenue": 100,
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "GRS",
    "segment": "D",
    "metric": "2021",
    "revenue": 100,
  }
]
```

After aggregation, I want the result to come in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "invoice_id": "GRS",
    "segment": "D",
    "2019": 100,
    "2021": 100
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "RET",
    "segment": "D",
    "2019": 100,
    "2020": 100
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "GRS",
    "segment": "R",
    "2019": 100,
    "2021": 100
  },
  {
    "invoice_id": "RET",
    "segment": "R",
    "2021": 100
  },
]
```

Comment: Do you like to sum the revenues? Or do you have always one revenue value per year?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by `invoice_id`, `segment` and `metric` and get total sum of `revenue`
- `$group` by `invoice_id` and `segment` and construct array of years in key-value pair
- `$arrayToObject` convert `years` array to object key-value format
- `$mergeObject` to merge `_id` object and `years` object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above merge object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        invoice_id: "$invoice_id",
        segment: "$segment",
        metric: "$metric"
      },
      revenue: { $sum: "$revenue" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        invoice_id: "$_id.invoice_id",
        segment: "$_id.segment"
      },
      years: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.metric",
          v: "$revenue"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$_id",
          { $arrayToObject: "$years" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L5mLgtMk_eZ)